# How to sort OrderedDict

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddict

I want to sort a dict by values and then if values are equal, then sort by alphabetic key:

```
od=OrderedDict(sorted(zhanr.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True))
```

I tried this code for values but don't know how to sort by the key if the values are equal.

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: I solved it:
dic_sorted = {k : v for k,v in sorted(zhanr.items(), key= lambda item: (item[0],item[1]))}
dd=OrderedDict(sorted(dic_sorted.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True))
for key,value in dd.items():
 print (key,':',value)

Answer (score 2):

i think this would work for you:

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[::-1])
```

which is the same as:

```
def reverse_tuple(t):
    return t[::-1]

sorted(dictionary.items(), key=reverse_tuple)
```

Comment: I do it but it didnt work